# Trying to aggregate data in R

Tags: r

[I have this data set right there that I need to aggregate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wG1pV.png)

```
aggregate(credit$Amount~credit$`Transaction Date`,credit,sum)
```

I tried that code but it has been giving me only the totals amount of March and February whereas I need the amounts of March and February broken out by categories like food & drink and travel.

Comment: You can sum using two different categories by including them inside the list like this `aggregate(credit, by = list(credit$Transaction Date, credit$another category), FUN = sum)`

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(...)`) directly.